# Sorting an ADT Queue

Tags: java, queue, quicksort, adt

I'm tasked to create a `Person` class that holds their name and age, create a Queue class that can hold an array of objects and then sort them alphabetically and by age using the `quicksort` algorithm.

When I try to call `Sort.quickSort` in the Driver class, I get a compiler error. I'm not sure what to change, any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class Queue<T> {
    private T[] queue;
    private int frontIndex;
    private int backIndex;
    private static final int DEFAULT_INTIIAL_CAPACITY = 50;

    public Queue() {
        this(DEFAULT_INTIIAL_CAPACITY);
    }

    public Queue(int initialCapacity) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] tempQueue = (T[]) new Object[initialCapacity + 1];
        queue = tempQueue;
        backIndex = initialCapacity;
        frontIndex = 0;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return queue.length;
    }

    public T[] getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    Boolean isEmpty() {
        return frontIndex == ((backIndex + 1) % queue.length);
    }

    void enqueue(T newEntry) {
        ensureCapacity();
        backIndex = (backIndex + 1) % queue.length;
        queue[backIndex] = newEntry;
    }

    private void ensureCapacity() {
        if (frontIndex == ((backIndex + 2) % queue.length)) {
            T[] oldQueue = queue;
            int oldSize = oldQueue.length;

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T[] tempQueue = (T[]) new Object[2 * oldSize];
            queue = tempQueue;

            for (int index = 0; index < oldSize - 1; index++) {
                queue[index] = oldQueue[frontIndex];
                frontIndex = (frontIndex + 1) % oldSize;
            }
            frontIndex = 0;
            backIndex = oldSize % 2;
        }

    }

    T dequeue() {
        T front = null;
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            front = queue[frontIndex];
            queue[frontIndex] = null;
            frontIndex = (frontIndex + 1) % queue.length;
        }
        return front;
    }

    T getFront() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        else
            return queue[frontIndex];


    }

    public T[] toArray() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] result = (T[]) new Object[DEFAULT_INTIIAL_CAPACITY];

        for (int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
            result[i] = queue[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

}


public class Person {
    private String lastName, firstName;
    private int age;

    Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setAge(age);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getLastName() + ", " + getFirstName() + " - " + getAge();
    }

}


public class Sort {
    private static final int MIN_SIZE = 4;


    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sortFirstMiddleLast(T[] a, int first, int mid, int last) {
        if (a[first].compareTo(a[mid]) > 0)
            swap(a, first, mid);
        if (a[mid].compareTo(a[last]) > 0) {
            swap(a, mid, last);

            if (a[first].compareTo(a[mid]) > 0) {
                swap(a, first, mid);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void swap(Object[] array, int i, int j) {
        Object temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int partition(T[] a, int first, int last) {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        sortFirstMiddleLast(a, first, mid, last);
        swap(a, mid, last - 1);
        int pivotIndex = last - 1;
        T pivot = a[pivotIndex];

        int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
        int indexFromRight = last - 2;
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            while (a[indexFromLeft].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
                indexFromLeft++;

            while (a[indexFromRight].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
                indexFromRight--;

            if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {
                swap(a, indexFromLeft, indexFromRight);
                indexFromLeft++;
                indexFromRight--;
            } else
                done = true;
        }
        swap(a, pivotIndex, indexFromLeft);
        return pivotIndex;
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quickSort(T[] a, int first, int last) {
        if (last - first + 1 < MIN_SIZE)
            selectionSort(a);
        else {
            int pivotIndex = partition(a, first, last);
            quickSort(a, first, pivotIndex - 1);
            quickSort(a, pivotIndex + 1, last);
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void selectionSort(T[] a) {
        int last = a.length - 1;
        for (int index = 0; index < last; index++) {
            int indexNextSmallest = getIndexOfSmallest(a, index, last);
            swap(a, index, indexNextSmallest);
        }

    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int getIndexOfSmallest(T[] a, int first, int last) {
        T min = a[first];
        int indexOfMin = first;
        for (int index = first + 1; index <= last; index++) {
            if (a[index].compareTo(min) < 0) {
                min = a[index];
                indexOfMin = index;
            }
        }
        return indexOfMin;
    }
}


public class driver {

    public static <T> void main(String[] args) {
        Person one = new Person("Tyler", "Well", 19);
        Person two = new Person("Roy", "Ted", 19);
        Person three = new Person("Jerry", "Dots", 19);
        Person four = new Person("Something", "Test", 19);
        Person five = new Person("PlaceHolder", "Matt", 19);

        Queue<Person> persons = new Queue<Person>(5);

        persons.enqueue(one);
        persons.enqueue(two);
        persons.enqueue(three);
        persons.enqueue(four);
        persons.enqueue(five);

        Sort.quickSort(persons.getQueue(), 0, persons.getLength()); //error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically this would be a quicksort of an array. If the container interface is restricted to a true queue interface (first in, first out), then a traditional quicksort could not be used. With a second queue, a merge sort could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement the `Comparable` interface in your `Person` class.

Your `quickSort` method is asking for a type parameter T bounded to `Comparable`, which is not implemented by `Person`; hence the compiling error.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quickSort(T[] a , int first, int last)
```

Assuming you want to sort your `Person` instances by last name first, then first name and lastly age, your class `Person` should look like this:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    
    /* ... your implementation ... */

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName)
            .thenComparing(Person::getFirstName)
            .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge)
            .compare(this, o);
    }
}
```